# "this" undefined in exported react function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem:** When the exported function is called by my React component, `console.log(this)` displays undefined. I was expecting it to return the component since I have bound it in my constructor.

**Leaderboard.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {leaderboard, createLeaderboard} from '../utility/gamecode';

class Leaderboard extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.showLeaderboard = showLeaderboard.bind(this);
    this.state = {
    }
  };

  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.leaderboard){
      showLeaderboard();
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="leaderboard hidden">
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Leaderboard;
```

**gamecode.js:**

```
export function showLeaderboard(){
 console.log(this);
}
//-----------------------
export function createLeaderboard(props){
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `showLeaderboard` instead of `this.showLeaderboard` - the one you bound `this` to.

Comment: Good eye, that seems to have fixed my problem. :)